# Failed Raid 5 on Adaptec 2010S

Tags: hardware-raid, adaptec

had a major problem with my Raid 5 yesterday. Adaptec Controller showed all 4 drives with status failed and the array was on failed too.
I used raidutil to force it back to optimal state after reboot didn't help at all. Windows made a chkdsk and it found the two partitions of the raid and all the files were still there.

Is there any way to find out why the Raid and all drives failed? Could it be that some broken tape in a tapedrive on the same controller caused all the troubles? I did get timeouts from the tapedrive when i tried to eject the tape and short after this i had the crash.

How to check if the drives are broken and have to be switched and how to check if the files are still working after i got the array back to optimal? Will the Adaptec Storage Manager check this for me?

thx for the answers in advance.
Tobsen

Answer (score 2):

Might also pay to investigate the firmware revision of your raid controller, and if it is out of date see if there any any major bugfixes in a new version.

I've had an experience where not once, but twice, a server display a similar malfunction at one of our "big" sites. When the vendor was called in to explain, it was found that the firmware revision had a fault where it would cause striping errors on the RAID5 array. Updating the firmware resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check your logs or wherewer it would be for SCSI bus errors/failures.
It is surprisingly often that it's not disk who is at fault, but SCSI bus.

It can be bad termination, bad contacts, too much EM noise, gnomes...